# Custom Slack App to run commands from Slack to Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, integration, slack, slack-salesforce-app

**Problem Statement:** We have our UAT org whose access is restricted. Any time we want to run any test classes/any code in Dev Console etc, we need to reach to our admins and they do the tasks. This becomes difficult if Admin is on PTO or occupied with other tasks. Or in general also.

**Solution:** I have two solutions in mind currently.

1. Admin Panel: Implement a LWC page (Admin Panel) where in users can run the test class, execute code and both above things will happen in context of Admin user. (Not explored but I'm guessing we'll have to use Tooling API)
2. Slack to SF Integration: I'm thinking of creating a Slack App in which you can send your messages like *run this code* or *run test class* and Salesforce will then do the tasks.

I'm inclining towards Slack Integration one but need some assistance. I'm not sure whether reverse custom integration from Slack to Salesforce is possible. I was not able to find any documentation around that. If any of you have done this in the past or have an idea, could you please assist. Thanks.